# Problem calculating screen point for a point in a 3D world with view matrix and projection matrix

Tags: mathematics, camera, linear-algebra, projection-matrix

I am trying to calculate the 2D screen point of a 3D world position. For this I use the multiplication `ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix`. But I am not getting good results and I think I am messing up my calculations or my ViewMatrix itself is wrong (I think the latter).

This is a snapshot of how my `ViewMatrix` looks like when the camera is looking downwards (at my feet):

```
 0.362,    0.932,    0.000,    0.000
-2.241,    0.094,   -0.966,    0.000
-0.900,    0.350,    0.259,    0.000
 8.100,  -16.860,    4.598,    1.000
```

I calculate my left handed perspective `ProjectionMatrix` manually using `4/3` aspect ratio `60` FOV and using `0.1` and `1000` for my near and far Z. This is the ending projection matrix:

```
-0.117,    0.000,    0.000,    0.000
 0.000,   -0.156,    0.000,    0.000
 0.000,    0.000,    1.000,    1.000
 0.000,    0.000,   -0.100,    0.000
```

I multiply the previous 2 matrices with `ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix` and use that as my `ViewProjectionMatrix`.

Now I need to calculate the clipping space coordinates of the 3D point. I do this as follows:

```
XMFLOAT4 clipCoords;
clipCoords.x = pos.x * viewMatrix._11 + pos.y * viewMatrix._21 + pos.z * viewMatrix._31 + viewMatrix._41;
clipCoords.y = pos.x * viewMatrix._12 + pos.y * viewMatrix._22 + pos.z * viewMatrix._32 + viewMatrix._42;
clipCoords.z = pos.x * viewMatrix._13 + pos.y * viewMatrix._23 + pos.z * viewMatrix._33 + viewMatrix._43;
clipCoords.w = pos.x * viewMatrix._14 + pos.y * viewMatrix._24 + pos.z * viewMatrix._34 + viewMatrix._44;
```

Now I convert this to normalised device coordinates:

```
XMFLOAT3 NDC;
NDC.x = clipCoords.x / clipCoords.w;
NDC.y = clipCoords.y / clipCoords.w;
NDC.z = clipCoords.z / clipCoords.w;
```

As a final step I convert it to the 2D point on a screen for a given size:

```
XMFLOAT2 screen;
screen.x = (windowWidth / 2 * NDC.x) + (NDC.x + windowWidth / 2);
screen.y = -(windowHeight / 2 * NDC.y) + (NDC.y + windowHeight / 2);
```

Can you spot the problem with the above calculation?

Steffen

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is non-cumulative, aka `A * B` doesn't always equal to `B * A`. The order of the multiplications should be

```
projection * view * model * vector
```

Your projection matrix is also messed up, the values should be this way:

[image]

I would say where the values in your matrix are, but I have zero idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using the following function to calculate the projection matrix: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205350(v=vs.85).aspx. I think the issue lies in that the view matrix doesn't have any values at the last two columns of the first row.

Comment: @Steffen that shouldn't be a problem, did you try what I said?

Comment: @Steffen an image about the problem would also be nice